# 99 Bottle of Beer Recursion Doesn't Seem to Work

Tags: c, recursion

Ok here is the simple code i have written while on a learning process.

```
void SingTheSong (int NumOfBottles)
{
    if (NumOfBottles == 0){
        printf("there are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall. \n");
    }

    else {
        printf("%d bottles of beer on the wall, %d bottles of beer.\n", NumOfBottles, NumOfBottles);
        int Bottleless = NumOfBottles - 1;
        printf("Take one down pass it around, %d bottles of beer on the wall. \n", Bottleless);

        SingTheSong(Bottleless);
        printf("Put a bottle in the recycling bin, there are now %d empty bottles in the bin.\n", NumOfBottles);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    SingTheSong(99);
    return 0;
}
```

the only thing i cant understand is why does the SingTheSong(Botteless) function start at 1 when the program is run, and why does it show the printf() statement after there is 0 bottles of beer on the wall. Just a liuttle confused because i thought everything within the curly braces was exicuted in the else statement before it runs the else statement again. why isn't it like this?

Example:
 "99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer. Take one down, pass it around, 98 bottles of beer on the wall. 
Put a bottle in the recycling bin, there is now 1 empty bottles in the bin"
"98 bottles of beer on the wall, 98 bottles of beer. Take one down, pass it around, 97 bottles of beer on the wall. 
Put a bottle in the recycling bin, there is now 2 empty bottles in the bin"

i know his is beginner stuff, i am a beginner. can someone explain this to me so i stop going in circles. thanks!

Comment: do you know how recursion works? what happens when you return from a recursive call (or any function call)?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you know what `SingTheSong` method prints for `N`. Now trade the two branches of the `if` statement separately. When `NumOfBottles` is zero, print the "no bottles" message, and return. When `NumOfBottles` is not zero, we do the following three things:

- Print the number of bottles `N`
- Print whatever `SingTheSong` method prints for `N-1`
- Print the recycling message `N`

The middle line is *recursive*: it can be expanded into the same three lines, like this:

- Print the number of bottles `N`
- Print the number of bottles `N-1`
- Print whatever `SingTheSong` method prints for `N-2`
- Print the recycling message `N-1`
- Print the recycling message `N`

You can do it again and again, until the middle line becomes the "out of beer" message.

Answer (score 0):

You are recursing on your `SingTheSong` function *before* your `printf` about the number of bottles in the recycling bin.

There is also a flaw in the recycling bin logic--you need to pass the current number of bottles in the recycling bin to your function recursively -- the way it is now, if you fix the order of the lines as described above, it will always print one fewer than the total number of bottles on the wall as being in the bin.

Here's some pseudo-code to show what this kind of recursion should look like:

```
function singTheSong(bottlesOnWall,bottlesInBin) {
    if (bottlesOnWall == 0) {
        print("There are no more bottles.\n");
    } else {
        printf("%d bottles of beer on the wall, %d bottles of beer.\n", bottlesOnWall, bottlesOnWall);
        bottlesOnWall--;
        bottlesInBin++;
        printf("Take one down pass it around, %d bottles of beer on the wall.\n", bottlesOnWall);
        printf("Put a bottle in the recycling bin, there are now %d empty bottles in the bin.\n", bottlesInBin);
        singTheSong(bottlesOnWall,bottlesInBin);
    }
}

singTheSong(99,0);
```

Comment: the program builds and runs fine. if it prints one fewer in the bin than on the wall, shouldn't there be -1 bottles in the bin if the else statement ended and 0 bottles on the wall? or if took the first impression on ther being 99 bottles on the wall shouldent it say there is 98 bottles in the bin. i dont understand how the function ius counting down from 99n then moving up from 0?

Comment: ok i understand the code you wrote because singTheSong starts with 99 and 0 but what is the computer thought process when it only starts at 100 a a recursion comes into place.

Answer (score 0):

Um I don't understand where you're facing the problem but here goes the explanation:

for NumOfBottles = 99:

```
printf("%d bottles of beer on the wall, %d bottles of beer.\n", NumOfBottles, NumOfBottles); // = 99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer.
int Bottleless = NumOfBottles - 1; // 98
printf("Take one down pass it around, %d bottles of beer on the wall. \n", Bottleless); //98 bottles of beer on the wall. 
SingTheSong(98)
```

for NumOfBottles = 98:

```
printf("%d bottles of beer on the wall, %d bottles of beer.\n", NumOfBottles, NumOfBottles); //= 98 bottles of beer on the wall, 98 bottles of beer
int Bottleless = NumOfBottles - 1; // 97
printf("Take one down pass it around, %d bottles of beer on the wall. \n", Bottleless); //97 bottles of beer on the wall
SingTheSong(97);
```

...

At the end when NumOfBottles = 0:
    printf("there are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall. \n"); //there are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall. //now return!

now, this will be printed 99 times:

```
printf("Put a bottle in the recycling bin, there are now %d empty bottles in the bin.\n", NumOfBottles);//starting from 1 upto 99.
```

This is why its not like that, because the recursive function was called BEFORE that `printf("Put a bottle...")`.

Solution:

```
void SingTheSong (int NumOfBottles)
{
    if (NumOfBottles == 0){
       printf("there are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall. \n");
    } 


     else {
         printf("%d bottles of beer on the wall, %d bottles of beer.\n", NumOfBottles, NumOfBottles);
         int Bottleless = NumOfBottles - 1;
         printf("Take one down pass it around, %d bottles of beer on the wall. \n", Bottleless);
         printf("Put a bottle in the recycling bin, there are now %d empty bottles in the bin.\n", 99-Bottleless);
         SingTheSong(Bottleless);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer. Just showing what you may want to complement the other answers.

```
void SingTheSong (int bottlesOnWall, int bottlesInBin)
{
    if (bottlesOnWall == 0){
        printf("there are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall. \n");
    }

    else {
        printf("%d bottles of beer on the wall, %d bottles of beer.\n",bottlesOnWall, bottlesOnWall);
        printf("Take one down pass it around, %d bottles of beer on the wall. \n", --bottlesOnWall);
        printf("Put a bottle in the recycling bin, there are now %d empty bottles in the bin.\n", ++bottlesInBin);

        SingTheSong(bottlesOnWall, bottlesInBin);
    }
}
```

You can initially call the function like:

```
SingTheSong(99, 0);
```

Also, you may want to read more about [recursion](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson16.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is a function recursion，when you start SingTheSong(Bottleless) form 99 to 1，it will call function with the Bottleless as 99,98,97……1.after SingTheSong(1),then go on the printf

" printf("Put a bottle in the recycling bin, there are now %d empty bottles in the bin.\n", NumOfBottles);"

then back to SingTheSong(2),as it goes on,and finally got back SingTheSong(99)

Comment: THANK YOU THIS IS THE ANSWER I WAS LOOKING FOR!!! LOL ZND IT WAS THE SHORTEST, BUT THANKS EVERYONE ELSE TO.

Comment: @adobbs6017 You should consider marking the solution that helped as the answer to your question (click the green checkmark to the left of the answer).