# Recursion in C confusion

Tags: c, variables, recursion

I'm working through a book that includes a chapter that deals with recursion in C. It prints the 99 bottles song to the log. Here is the code:

```
void singTheSong (int numberOfBottles) {

    if (numberOfBottles == 0) {
        printf("There are no more bottles left.\n");
    } else {
        printf("%d bottles of bear on the wall, %d bottles of beer.\n", numberOfBottles,
               numberOfBottles);

        int oneFewer = numberOfBottles - 1;

        printf("Take one down, pass it around, %d bottles of beer on the wall.\n", oneFewer);

        singTheSong(oneFewer); 
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    singTheSong(99);
    return 0;
}
```

The output reads just like how the song is sang. What I'm having trouble understanding is, how does the `numberOfBottles` variable change its value? I see that it gets subtracted by one in the `oneFewer` variable, but I'm failing to understand how exactly this is working. It seems to me that the log would read "99 bottles of bear on the wall, 99 bottles of beer. Take one down, pass it around, 98 bottles of beer on the wall." repetitively, without ever dipping below 98. I'm not sure how `numberOfBottles` value is changed, and therefore how `oneFewer` keeps track of the number of bottles. One more question, is my confusion regarding this topic a bad sign for continuing on with programming? I had it nailed up until this point.

Comment: Why are there duplicates? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224759/99-bottle-of-beer-recursion-doesnt-seem-to-work

Comment: Don't feel bad that you don't get it immediately! Recursion can be a tough topic if you're just getting into it. You might want to try http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts/courses/cs106b/chapters/05-intro-to-recursion.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot nullptr, that's encouraging! And sorry Aniket, that didn't turn up in my search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key is here:

```
    int oneFewer = numberOfBottles - 1;
    singTheSong(oneFewer);
```

A new call to `singTheSong` is generated, where `numberOfBottles` is 98 instead of 99.  That function gets a local copy of `numberOfBottles` with the value of 98.

```
Stack                                  numberOfBottles
------------------------------------------------------
singTheSong                            99
  singTheSong                          98
    singTheSong                        97
      singTheSong                      96
        ...                            ...
          singTheSong                  1
            singTheSong                0
```

By the time `numberOfBottles` hits zero, there are 100 nested calls to `singTheSong` sitting on the stack.  Finally, the function returns without doing a recursion, and all the copies up the stack that were waiting will return one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Take a piece of paper and draw the call stack per each invocation, recording the value of the argument, and the return address (so you can see it *unwind*). It should be easier to follow.

The execution will always go into the `else` block, except for the last (the *base case*), where it will go into the `if` block. This will mean the number will be decremented until it reaches `0`.

Answer (score 2):

The first time `singTheSong` is called, `numberOfBottles` is `99`.

It then calls `singTheSong(numberOfBottles-1)` (`99 - 1 = 98`), which will then call `singTheSong(numberOfBottles-1)` with the *new number of bottles*, ie `98 - 1 = 97`.

The process repeats until the base case is reached.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your last question first - no, this doesn't necessarily mean your programming career is doomed.  Recursion is important to understand, but most of its good functional uses (walking trees and graphs jump to mind) are already implemented in libraries where you don't need to understand it in depth.  When you get to functional programming, it will matter more, but by then, you'll have a good grasp of it.

What it shows you don't understand is the nature of functions and what the call stack does.  That will be important to learn, and recursion is a good way to do it.

The thing about recursion is that it results in many calls of the same function on a call stack.  In this case, when you start at 99, yes, `oneFewer` = 98.  But then, before you finish the function, you call `singTheSong` passing in oneFewer, i.e. 98.  And that will call `singTheSong` with a `oneFewer` value of 97.

This will result in you having 100 instances of the same function all stacked up on your call stack.  On the 100th song, you print "There are no bottles left", and your function exits.  Then the function for "1 bottle" has completed, so it exits, allowing the "2 bottles" function to complete, and so on all the way through your call stack, until the originating function completes.

Comment: Great advice and description.

Answer (score 2):

The thing to understand is that the function singTheSong is calling itself. So the function  main calls singTheSong(99).  This function prints some things out, and then sticks 99 - 1 in the variable oneFewer, and then it calls singTheSong again with the value of oneFewer.  So this time, the value that it is passed is not 99, it is 98.

The new function is a different instance of singTheSong. It doesn't know anything about the singTheSong that was called before. All it knows is that it was was given the value 98, and it should print some things out, stick 98-1 into oneFewer, and then call singTheSong AGAIN.

By the time the program gets down to 0, there will actually be 99 instances of singTheSong. But when it gets called with zero, instead of recursing again, it just prints "There are no bottles left".  Then the program returns back up through all 99 cases and finally ends. 0 is thus the *base case*, and it is vital that every recursive algorithm have a base case that is reached.

If you want to understand this more, try putting a printf("%d %d \n",oneFewer, numberOfBottles);  after the recursive call.

If you want to crash your computer (and see what this site is named for), try removing the if statement and the "there are not bottles left" base case.

Comment: Just a nitpick - 99 down to 0 gives you 100 instances.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

After the "take one down, pass it around" statement,

```
singTheSong(oneFewer);
```

is being called with oneFewer, which is the variable that holds the value of the number of bottles in that specific iteration. So numberOfBottles is 99 at first, then oneFewer gets assigned to 98. Then, oneFewer = 98, is passed onto singTheSong. This time, the argument which is referred to as *numberOfBottles* has the same value as oneFewer from the previous iteration. In this iteration, oneFewer obtains the value of 97 and this cycle goes on until the base case is reached which is when oneFewer is 0 and is passed into singTheSong. singTheSong takes that value and knows that it has reached the *if* case so it stops.

Comment: So basically since the recursion call `singTheSong(oneFewer);` has the argument of oneFewer, it assigns the numberOfBottles variable to == oneFewer as the stacks keep climbing?

Comment: That is precisely the case :) If you understand that, you understand most of recursion.